# Flutter Web - Send Mail directly from Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, email, sendmail, flutter-web

I am developing a website with flutter web.
But I can't find a plugin or something to be able to send emails directly from a contact form

How can I send an email directly from flutter web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending emails via the client-side (e.g. Flutter) is not recommended and has lots of security issues. You will have to put some private information in your app and anyone can access this information.

So the correct way to do this is by using a backend(e.g. Node.js) and make your Flutter app communicate with this backend via sending a post HTTP request.

You can easily achieve that using some node js packages like [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/)

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to a possible solution!  Do you have any example of how to create the server in js and communicate with flutter web? Thanks again!